# How to draw a dotted circle using python Turtle package

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Something similar to the picture attached. I tried modifying the code I got online. But my code goes to infinity loop
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfKog.png

```
def draw_circle(radius):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(0, radius)  # go to (0, radius)
    turtle.pendown()  # pen down
    times_y_crossed = 0
    x_sign = 1.0
    while times_y_crossed <= 1:
        turtle.dot(5, "Red")
        turtle.forward(5)  # move by 1/360
        turtle.right(1.0)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.forward(5)  # move by 1/360
        turtle.right(1.0)
        x_sign_new = math.copysign(1, turtle.xcor())
        if x_sign_new != x_sign:
            times_y_crossed += 10
        x_sign = x_sign_new
    turtle.up()  # pen up
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code, like it does not count with the radius and the color for the pen was not set and as I've checked it did a half circle for me.
I show you a simple working example, first a dashed version because your original code looks like you wanted a dashed circle

```
import turtle
import math
def draw_circle_dashed(radius):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(0, radius)  # go to (0, radius)
    times_y_crossed = 0
    dist=2*math.pi*radius/360
    turtle.pencolor("red")
    for _ in range(180):
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.forward(dist)  # move by 1/360
        turtle.right(1.0)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.forward(dist)  # move by 1/360
        turtle.right(1.0)
    turtle.up()  # pen up
    return
draw_circle_dashed(200)
```

and a dotted variant as well because of the question title

```
import turtle
import math
def draw_circle_dotted(radius):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(0, radius)  # go to (0, radius)
    dist=2*math.pi*radius/360
    for _ in range(360):
        turtle.dot(2,"red")
        turtle.forward(dist)  # move by 1/360
        turtle.right(1.0)
    turtle.up()  # pen up
    return
draw_circle_dotted(300)
```

Comment: To be clear, this draws a *dashed* circle, not a *dotted* circle as the OP desires and illustrates.  The dotted circle adds complexity.

Comment: Actually not, the dotted variant is easy as well.

Comment: Code doesn't appear to adjust for dot diameter so doesn't look right with the OP's dot diameter of 5 instead of 2.  That's where the additional complexity comes in.

Answer (score 0):

We can use turtle's own `circle()` method to do this as we can arbitrarily start and stop it, leaving behind dots as we do:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from math import pi

DOT_DIAMETER = 5

def draw_circle(radius):
    turtle.penup()

    circumference = 2 * pi * radius

    dot_extent = 360 * DOT_DIAMETER*2 / circumference  # diameter to angle

    extent = 0
    while extent < 360:
        turtle.dot(DOT_DIAMETER)
        turtle.circle(radius, extent=dot_extent)

        extent += dot_extent

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.color('red')

draw_circle(100)

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Using what we learned from that exercise, let's now fix your code.  The issue I see is this:

```
turtle.right(1.0)
```

The angle to turn is dependent on the dot diameter, but we actually have to *calculate* it:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from math import pi, copysign

DOT_DIAMETER = 5

def draw_circle(radius):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.sety(radius)

    diameter = 2 * radius
    circumference = pi * diameter
    dot_extent = 360 * DOT_DIAMETER / circumference  # diameter to angle

    times_y_crossed = 0
    x_sign = 1

    while times_y_crossed < 2:
        turtle.dot(DOT_DIAMETER, 'red')  # draw the dot
        turtle.right(dot_extent)
        turtle.forward(DOT_DIAMETER)

        turtle.right(dot_extent)  # draw the gap
        turtle.forward(DOT_DIAMETER)

        x_sign_new = copysign(1, turtle.xcor())

        if x_sign_new != x_sign:
            times_y_crossed += 1
            x_sign = x_sign_new

    turtle.pendown()

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.color('red')

draw_circle(100)

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

By not calculating the angle, and using a fixed angle of 1.0, you were off by a factor of two.

[image]